# Extract a table without class or id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from http://marine-transportation.capitallink.com/indices/baltic_exchange_history.html?ticker=BDI

Although it seemed fairly easy it is not possible for me to identify the table in such a way that i could scrape it, i'm not able to extract the data. Can any one help with the right identification

```
import urllib3 
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv
import re


url = 'http://marine-transportation.capitallink.com/indices/baltic_exchange_history.html?ticker=BDI'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
col = row.find_all('td')
column_1 = col[0].string.strip()

#
date = []
closing_rate = []

#Here i need a reference to the correct table
table = soup.find()

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')

    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    date.append(column_1)
    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    closing_rate.append(column_2)



columns = {'date': date, 'closing_rate': ClosingRate}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)

df.to_csv('Baltic_Dry.csv')
```

Comment: The page requires a login

Answer (score 2):

You could use unique style attributes to identify the table you need.

For example, on this page [here](http://marine-transportation.capitallink.com/indices/capital_link_maritime_history.html?ticker=CLCI), it looks like the table containing index data is 550px wide. You can use:

`soup.findAll('table', width="550")`

*Please note: I had to use another page on the same website because the one you posted requires a login. Hopefully the page structure will be similar.*